FlutterLoader is not defined for web
I have problem 
I dont know why but my web app is build correctly but when I use chrome for my web then I have white page and in console I have error: FlutterLoader is not defined.
My index.html page looks like this:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="architect_schwarz_admin">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>web admin</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = '{{flutter_service_worker_version}}';
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      if (typeof FlutterLoader !== 'undefined') {
        // Download main.dart.js
        FlutterLoader.load({
          serviceWorker: {
            serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
          },
          onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
            engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
              appRunner.runApp();
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.error('FlutterLoader is not defined.');
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>



Image from console google chrome  

Do you know what is the problem?

Take a look at the official documentation.
It's not FlutterLoader, but, rather:

_flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
          serviceWorker: {

I suppose you are using a deprecated version.
Your entire index.html should look like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="architect_schwarz_admin">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>web admin</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = '{{flutter_service_worker_version}}';
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
    // Download main.dart.js
    _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
      serviceWorker: {
        serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
      },
      onEntrypointLoaded: async function(engineInitializer) {
        // Initialize the Flutter engine
        let appRunner = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
        // Run the app
        await appRunner.runApp();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>

As you can see, there are no errors in the console:

